# Is there any way to remove specific key value when iterating over list of dictionaries in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have below data in CSV format

instance_id,Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,Tag4
instance1,no,test,lite,no
instance2,yes,dev,enterprise,yes

when I read this data using:-

```
    read_csv:  
       path: <csv path>  
    register: instance
  - debug: var=instance
```

Upon debugging I get:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {  
        "instance": {  
            "changed": false,  
            "dict": {},  
            "failed": false,  
            "list": [  
                {  
                    "Tag1": "no",  
                    "Tag2": "test",  
                    "Tag3": "lite",  
                    "Tag4": "no",  
                    "instance_id": "instance1"  
                },  
                {  
                    "Tag1": "yes",  
                    "Tag2": "dev",  
                    "Tag3": "enterprise",  
                    "Tag4": "yes",  
                    "instance_id": "instance2"  
                }  
            ]  
       }  
   }
```

Now I want to update Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4 on respective instance1, and instance2.
I tried:-

```
  ec2_tag:
     region: us-west-1
     resource: "{{ instances.instance_id }}"
     state: present
     tags: "{{ instance.list[0] }}"


  loop: "{{ instance.list }}"
  loop_control:
         loop_var: instances
```

I am getting the desired result however I am getting instance_id also as a Tag. See below example

Tags for instance1 on my AWS console are :
Tag1: no
Tag2: test
Tag3: lite
Tag4: no
instance_id: instance1 {I do not want this as my tag attached to my instance}

Similarly, for instance2, I am getting respective tags:
Tag1: yes
Tag2: dev
Tag3: enterprise
Tag4: yes
instance_id: instance2 {I do not want this as my tag attached to my instance}

Comment: Please take some time to format your question correctly, especially the code. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Id it clear or do I need to edit it?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip list of dictionnary elements based on a test on one of their attribute with the `selectattr`/`rejectattr` [jinja2 builtin filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters), as demonstrated in the following playbook. Note that I used equality with `rejectattr` for a simple example, but you can use any other test you want (see [jinja2 builtin tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#builtin-tests) and [ansible specific ones](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html)) and switch to `selectattr` which uses the same syntax if more convenient.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
    my_csv:
      - field1: a
        field2: b
        field3: c
      - field1: d
        field2: value to skip
        field3: f
      - field1: x
        field2: y
        field3: z

  tasks:
    - name: rejectattr demo
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_csv | rejectattr('field2', 'eq', 'value to skip') | list }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [rejectattr demo] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "field1": "a",
            "field2": "b",
            "field3": "c"
        },
        {
            "field1": "x",
            "field2": "y",
            "field3": "z"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Actually, my problem and my data are a little bit different. I am trying to automate tagging on my endpoints. Data I have in my CSV contains instance id and their respective tags to be updated. After reading the CSV, I am able to put tags on their respective instances. Problem is that while reading CSV, instance id also comes as one of the parameters in the list of dictionaries and gets updated with tags. Now, I need it to know what data I need to put for what instance ID but I do not want instance ID to be updated under tags.

Comment: How about editing your question and making it [MCVE](/help/mcve) then ?

Comment: Hope this helps to understand

Comment: Don't spread the needed info to answer your question over comments. Edit your question and add it there.